# stream youtube video from myserver laravel

Tags: python, php, laravel, youtube, youtube-api

I am working on a system that will work on the local network  , for some reason users will not have access to the internet,  the only access that allowed  to  those users is my  server,  and my server has full access to the internet, so  what I  want is to stream video  from youtube to my server to  my  client

```
youtube -----> server ------>client
```

I searched a lot but  I  could found any things that might help me,  most of the people talked about streaming live videos which I  don't want,  I  want to stream any video on youtube to my server, then the client will get the video from my server.
is it possible to do this?
I am using laravel  to develop my system,  but I  can  use python / node js if it is not possible in laravel

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at [pytube](https://github.com/pytube/pytube) package.

you can download a youtube video and save it to your server and start streaming in your proper way in laravel.

Comment: thank you for your reply , actually, I can upload the video to my  server  directly,  but what I  want is for marketing purpose , so I  can gain more view in the youtube channel , actually this is the goal of my project

Comment: actually what you wanted to create violates the purpose of fair view.
why don't you just use the embeded tags from youtube ?